# How can i capture a value from one dropdown menu when multiple are present?

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net

I am creating a table of components, and need the ability to add items from a dropdown list to each item in the table. These lists are added programmatically  using a foreach like this:

```
MyDatabase db = new MyDatabase();

if (db.ComponentTypes.Count() > 0)
{
    foreach (ComponentType componentType in db.ComponentTypes)
    {
        // Header row components
        TableRow componentRow = new TableRow();
        TableCell componentTypeCell = new TableCell();

        // Create Header Row
        componentTypeCell.ColumnSpan = 5;
        componentTypeCell.Text = componentType.Name;
        componentTypeCell.Attributes.Add("style", "background: black; color: white; font-weight: bold;");

        componentRow.Cells.Add(componentTypeCell);
        tblRigActionTypesAndComponentTypes.Rows.Add(componentRow);

        // Middle portion omitted for simplicity

        //=================================================
        // Relevant portion

        // DDL Row Components
        TableRow addActionRow = new TableRow();
        TableCell rigActionTypeMenuCell = new TableCell();
        TableCell addRigActionTypeButtonCell = new TableCell();
        DropDownList ddlRigActionTypeMenu = new DropDownList();
        Button addRigActionTypeButton = new Button();

        // Populate dropdown with action types
        Helper.PopulateDropdownWithActionTypes(ddlRigActionTypeMenu);
        rigActionTypeMenuCell.Controls.Add(ddlRigActionTypeMenu);

        addRigActionTypeButton.Text = "Add This Action";
        addRigActionTypeButton.CommandName = "Add";
        addRigActionTypeButton.CommandArgument = componentType.ID.ToString();
        addRigActionTypeButtonCell.ColumnSpan = 4;
        addRigActionTypeButtonCell.Controls.Add(addRigActionTypeButton);

        addActionRow.Cells.Add(rigActionTypeMenuCell);
        addActionRow.Cells.Add(addRigActionTypeButtonCell);
        tblRigActionTypesAndComponentTypes.Rows.Add(addActionRow);
    }
}
```

**Button Handler**

```
protected void ButtonHandler(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Button button = (Button)sender;
    MyDatabase db = new MyDatabase();

    if (button.CommandName == "Add")
    {
        // How do I capture the selected value from the 
        // dropdown menu paired with the "add" button?   
    }
}
```

Capturing the component the button belongs to is easy using the `CommandArgument` property, but how can I get the corresponding DDL?

**Update: Moe S' Method**

I have been unable to get this to work. I have tried a few different ways to access the dropdown menu using `button.NamingContainer`, but keep hitting a `Object reference not set to an instance of an object.` error. My last attempt is below:

```
Control control = button.NamingContainer;
Control test = control.FindControl("ddlRigActionTypeMenu");
lblPageHeader.Text = test.UniqueID;
```

**Update 2:**

To shed some additional light on the above (non-working) code, the following DOES work:

```
Control control = button.NamingContainer;
lblPageHeader.Text = button.NamingContainer.UniqueID;
```

This changes the page header to `dnn$ctr498$AssignRigActionTypesToComponentTypes`

**Solved**

I am marking Moe as the accepted answer on this because he got me pointed in the right direction, but `Parent` was what ended up working for me, not `NamingContainer`. All of the same principles still apply though.

**Solution:**

DropDownList ddl = (DropDownList)((TableRow)((TableCell)button.Parent).Parent).Cells[0].Controls[0];

Comment: is this winforms, WPF, web application?

Comment: @BlackICE No, it isn't. Thank you for the response though!

Comment: what kind of application is it then?

Comment: @BlackICE DotNetNuke 5. (unfortunately)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should be able to use the following to access the table row:

```
TableRow tblRow = (TableRow) button.NamingContainer;
```

And then use the FindControl option to access the DropDownList

```
DropDownList ddlMenu = (DropDownList) tblRow.FindControl("ddlRigActionTypeMenu");
```

And then obviously SelectedValue to capture the value

Comment: I was unable to get this to work. Can you take a look at my update and see if you have any idea what's wrong? (I tried this exactly as you have it too, that also did not work)

Comment: Try debugging your code to see if your variable 'button' is returning null prior to using NamingContainer to obtain reference to the parent control. You may want to try casting your button object as well to see if that helps.

Comment: I just added another update. It looks like button isn't null. Any other ideas?

Comment: That's interesting...

Assuming my hierarchy of control is correct, could you tell if you get null for **tblRow**..

**TableRow tblRow = (TableRow)((TableCell) ((Button) Sender).NamingContainer).NamingContainer;**

Comment: It looks like it is hanging at the table cell cast: `Unable to cast object of type 'ASP.desktopmodules_robinson_maintenance_assignrigactiontypestocomponenttypes_ascx' to type 'System.Web.UI.WebControls.TableCell'.`

Comment: `Parent` was what ended up working. Your solution worked when I used that (see update). Thanks for all of your help!